# Illustrator CS3 Live Trace not working with a placed image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, cs3, live-trace

I am trying to convert my drawing (black and white) into a vector graphic using Illustrator CS3. When I place and select the drawing on the canvas and  when I press the Live Trace button... nothing happens! Have a missed a step?

Comment: You selected the placed image, right?

Answer (score -1):

There's a couple of options you can do. First place the image into illustrator and if you would like to do live trace you can select that and you can select your output options such as 3 color, high res drawing, etc. Embed the image and you can also "expand" it to move around the different shapes.